# SELECT from MYSQL with INNER JOIN on multiples of the same ID

Tags: php, mysql, join

So im just wondering if the next is possible and if so how to approach this.

I created an INNER JOIN query to SELECT multiple ID's from on a table where it is equal to the ID value from another table.

1. **Product** table

   ```
   product_id  |  cults_id1 |  cults_id2 | cults_id3
   -----------------------------------------------------
        1      |      5     |     4      |     2 
        2      |      3     |     0      |     0
   ```

   2. **Cultivar** table

      ```
      cults_id  |  cults_name |       
      ---------------------------
           1    |  berries    |  
           2    |  fruit      |  
           3    |  choc       |  
           4    |  wood       | 
           5    |  mysql!     |
      ```

So i created an join where it will fetch all the `cults_name` based on the product tables `cults_id1,  cults_id2, cults_id3`

**Result:**

`Product_id(1)  =  mysql! , wood , fruit`

Now the problem comes with the next one how can i display the one value that `product_id(2)` contains.

So it would result in looking like this:

`Product_id(1)  =  mysql! , wood , fruit`

`Product_id(2)  =  choc`

At this moment `product_id(2)` wont display in my listing because it has no resemble to the **Cultivar** table after the first ID, (using this query).

I know normalisation should be considered.

**Query**

```
   SELECT p.product_image_path, p.product_id, p.brand_name, p.product_name, b.botttle_size, v.vintage, 
   t.wine_type_blend, p.price, p.quantity, p.time_created, p.reference_number, p.shipping_cost, 
   c1.cultivar_type as cultivar_type1, c2.cultivar_type as cultivar_type2, 
   c3.cultivar_type as cultivar_type3, c4.cultivar_type as cultivar_type4
   FROM product p
   INNER JOIN wine_bottle b ON b.bottle_id = p.bottle_id 
   INNER JOIN wine_vintage v ON v.vintage_id = p.vintage_id 
   INNER JOIN wine_type t ON t.type_id = p.type_id
   INNER JOIN wine_cultivar c1 ON c1.cultivar_id = p.cultivar_1_id
   INNER JOIN wine_cultivar c2 ON c2.cultivar_id = p.cultivar_2_id
   INNER JOIN wine_cultivar c3 ON c3.cultivar_id = p.cultivar_3_id
   INNER JOIN wine_cultivar c4 ON c4.cultivar_id = p.cultivar_4_id
```

Now my product listing page has this to display it in listing but i want to display even if `cults_id1,  cults_id2, cults_id3` has an value of `0`.

**Product-listing.php**

```
   <?php
      if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
      $i = 0;      
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $i++;

      echo "
      <p>Cultivars: <span>" .$row["cultivar_type1"]. "</span>, <span>" .$row["cultivar_type2"]. "</span>, <span>" .$row["cultivar_type3"]. "</span>, <span>" .$row["cultivar_type4"]. "</span></p> ";
      }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
     }

    }
```

Output:

```
  Product_id(1)  =  mysql! , wood , fruit
```

Expected:

```
  Product_id(1)  =  mysql! , wood , fruit

  Product_id(2)  =  choc
```

Comment: This looks like poor structure to me. What if there was a fourth cult? If you know normalisation should be considered, why aren't you considering it?

Comment: @Strawberry the cultivars comes from an multiple select, wil always be 4 or less than 4 .. and also would follow up on each other so `cult_id_3` would never have a value if `cult_id_2` does not have one, im so far in this small project that im just trying to accomplish something , moving back now would result in allot of changes. I am defs going to do this over but just for now looking for a way around this.

Comment: Just for now, I'd restructure your schema. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only thing that i needed to to was to create an `LEFT JOIN`. Because an `LEFT JOIN` can accept 0 or an value. And my query worked.

Yes this my mysql DB is not the normalized as would be expected.

**Solution:**

```
 SELECT p.product_image_path, p.product_id, p.brand_name, p.product_name, b.botttle_size, v.vintage, 
   t.wine_type_blend, p.price, p.quantity, p.time_created, 
   p.reference_number, p.shipping_cost, 
   c1.cultivar_type as cultivar_type1, c2.cultivar_type as cultivar_type2, 
   c3.cultivar_type as cultivar_type3, c4.cultivar_type as cultivar_type4
 FROM product p
  INNER JOIN wine_bottle b ON b.bottle_id = p.bottle_id 
  INNER JOIN wine_vintage v ON v.vintage_id = p.vintage_id 
  INNER JOIN wine_type t ON t.type_id = p.type_id
  LEFT JOIN wine_cultivar c1 ON c1.cultivar_id = p.cultivar_1_id
  LEFT JOIN wine_cultivar c2 ON c2.cultivar_id = p.cultivar_2_id
  LEFT JOIN wine_cultivar c3 ON c3.cultivar_id = p.cultivar_3_id
  LEFT JOIN wine_cultivar c4 ON c4.cultivar_id = p.cultivar_4_id
```